# SQLAlchemy testing data to associative object

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, associative-table

I'm building an DB using sqlalchemy, and I would like to test my model. Even if I read few topics and going through the documentation, I'm not sure I understood how to load data into the associative tables.
I created the two classes this way :

```py
class Instance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Instances'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String, nullable=False)
    env = Column(String(3), nullable=False)
    code = Column(String, nullable=False) 

    customer = relationship('CustomerInstance', back_populates='instance')


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Customers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    code = Column(String, nullable=False)

    instance = relationship('CustomerInstance', back_populates='customer')

class CustomerInstance(Base):
    __tablename__='Customers_Instances'

    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Customers.id'), primary_key=True)
    instance_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Instances.id'), primary_key=True)

    instance = relationship('Instance', back_populates='customer')
    customer = relationship('Customer', back_populates='instance')
```

Then I create my session and flush it:

```
session = Session()

session.add_all([
    Instance(url='www.web.com', env='prd', code='123'),
    Instance(url='www.123.com', env='prd', code='321'),
    Instance(url='www.qwe.com', env='prd', code='345'),
    Instance(url='www.rty.com', env='prd', code='678'),
    Instance(url='www.hello.com', env='tes', code='098'),
    Instance(url='www.hi.com', env='uat', code='567'),
    Customer(name='ABC', code='567'),
    Customer(name='DEF', code='000'),
    Customer(name='GHI', code='123'),
    Customer(name='KLM', code='456')
])

session.commit()
```

Now how do I populate the object/table `CustomerInstance`, since it is composed by 2 Id's only? Am I on the right way? Same question, how to inject data into a table where the primary_key is a FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either assign the linked instances via a `relationship` or issue a `flush` of your linked objects (after the flush, the primary keys of the newly created objects get populated) and assign the ids manually.

### Example

```py
instance = CustomerInstance(
    instance=Instance(url='example.com', env='prd', code=123),
    customer=Customer(name='ABC', code='123'),
)
session.add(instance)

# SQLAlchemy will handle the foreign keys itself.
session.flush()
```

or

```py
instance = Instance(url='example.com', env='prd', code=123),
customer = Customer(name='ABC', code='123'),
session.add_all([instance, customer])
session.flush()

# Now the primary keys are populated!
cust_instance = CustomerInstance(
    customer_id=customer.id,
    instance_id=instance.id,
)
```

Comment: I tried the first way but it does not work : i m getting

   '''CustomerInstance is taking 1 positional argument but 3 given'''


also how can i make a many-to-many relationship with an other association object?

Comment: The standard `constructor` argument of `declarative_base` is `sqlalchemy.declarative.base._declarative_constructor` which only takes keyword arguments. If you built your base-class differently, you'll have to pass the arguments differently.